# Headers not sent with the request through a proxy server

Tags: node.js, express, header, proxy-server

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import axios from 'axios';

import service_ip_map from '../ip_addr';

export default async function escort_controller(req: Request, res: Response, _next: NextFunction) {
  const headers = { service_name: req.params.service_name, ...req.headers };

  const target_service = {
    ip: service_ip_map[req.params.service_name],
    method: req.method,
    body: req.body,
    headers,
    route: req.url,
    // url: req.originalUrl.split('/')[req.originalUrl.split('/').length - 1],
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: `${target_service.method}`,
      url: `http://${target_service.ip}${target_service.route}`,
      headers,
      data: target_service.body,
    });

    res.send({ data: response.data });
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error);
  }
}
```

In the above code I am trying to create a proxy server where I am capturing `req.headers` and passing it down through axios to another service. The issue is that the request just hangs and doesn't resolve (through postman).

But if I add custom headers like in the below example it works fine.

```
const target_service = {
    ip: service_ip_map[req.params.service_name],
    method: req.method,
    body: req.body,
    headers: {
      test_header: 'testing'
    },
    route: req.url,
    // url: req.originalUrl.split('/')[req.originalUrl.split('/').length - 1],
  };
```

Also When I make the same request through the browser and add some headers (be it from. req.headers or any custom headers for testing purposes those headers also don't show up in the browser, but the request doesn't hang up or fail in any way.

I tried to shallow copy the `req.headers` but that didn't work.

Comment: An update on this is that when I manually tried to add 
{
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.36.0',
      accept: '*/*',
      host: '127.0.0.1:8000',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      connection: 'keep-alive',
      'content-length': '28',
    },
as headers the same happens (request hangs up)
but any other custom header works fine